# How to return in the parent function context from a child function

Tags: javascript

I want the return to be in my parent function, for example:

```
  const blockLetters = lastD => {
    if(lastD != undefined && isNaN(Number.parseInt(lastD))){
      return;

    }
  }

const handleCVC = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newcvc = e.target.value;
    let newcvcArr = newcvc.split("");
    let newLength = (e.target.value).length;
    let lastNewDigit = newcvcArr[newLength-1]

    blockLetters(lastNewDigit);

    setcvc(newcvc)


  }
```

The purpose is that the returns; of the blockLetters affect directly the handleCVC function and it dont excecute his last line, but actually this returns; only affects the blockLetters function.

Comment: You can't do that. You can try throwing an error, but I wouldn't do that

Answer (score 3):

You could take a function which returns a `true`/truthy for not having a valid value for checking and returning in a calling function.

Actually it boils down to `isNaN` which could be used instead of having a dedicated function.

```
const isNoNumber = lastD => isNaN(Number.parseInt(lastD, 10));

const handleCVC = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newcvc = e.target.value;
    let newcvcArr = newcvc.split("");
    let newLength = (e.target.value).length;
    let lastNewDigit = newcvcArr[newLength-1];

    if (isNoNumber(lastNewDigit)) return;

    setcvc(newcvc);
}
```